# Kafka stream - Bidirectional

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Suppose I want to implement an application that act as a producer and consumer simultaneously. The client should be able to subscribe to a set of  topics and receive events.  It also should be able to reply back when it receives an event without requiring the producer to subscribe to a topic. Is that possible? What do you suggest? Do I need to use Kafka stream for that purpose?

Thanks,
Adib

Comment: I know about kafka my question is not about how to use kafka

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to do exactly. As noted by @WGSSAMINTHA, only consumers subscribe to topics. Producer can always write to any topic (as long as there are not ACL configured that restrict the access).

You can use `KafkaConsumer` and `KafkaProducer` in your application directly. This has the advantage that you have full flexibility in your application. However, you also need to take care of everything yourself.

It's also possible to use `KafkaStreams`. `KafkaStreams` has the advantage, that it provides higher level abstraction, offers build-in fault-tolerant state handling, and a high level DSL. It is less flexible than plain `KafkaConsumer` and `KafkaProducer` but might also be less work for you.

It's flexibility/convenience trade-off.

Answer (score 0):

Only consumer need to subscribe to topic because consumer always listen to topic and pick the events.

Producers just send event to topics and don't need to listen the topics.

Comment: I removed ELK from the answer, but I'd suggest using Kafka Connect for Elasticsearch rather than a plain Producer